# app.get('') is not working in node js with query parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

Iam trying to provide a new route for my conversation application where it should accept the parameters passed along with the route should be accepted and can be used in client side.But I couldnt figure out why basic .get() is not working ,where Iam unable to render the html.

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express'); // app server
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // parser for post requests
var Conversation = require('watson-developer-cloud/conversation/v1'); // watson sdk
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('./public')); // load UI from public folder
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/:id',function(req,res){
     var userid = req.params.id;
     var pid = req.query.pid;
     res.sendFile(__dirname,'/public/index.html');
});
module.exports = app;
```

On my localhost:3000 index file is getting loaded but for something like localhost:3000/3405?pid=CBM it is not loading.

Then I have a js file on client side which would require these two values id and pid.For now I just hardcoded.But how can I use these values  to client side js file..Can someone help me how can I do this...
Thanks

Updated :Adding my client side js file

```
var Api = (function() {
var messageEndpoint = '/api/message';
var emp = {
    "pid": "CBM",
    "id": "3405",};
return {
        sendRequest: sendRequest,
         modifytext: function(intent, text) {
            if (intent == "Hello") {
                console.log(text, "Inside intent");
                for (var key in emp) {
                    var tempKey = '{{' + key + '}}';
                    var tempValue = emp[key];
                    text = replace(text, tempKey, tempValue);
                    console.log("came back");
                }  
            }
            return text;
            console.log(text,"Final text");
        }
    };
    function replace(text, originalString, replaceText) {
        console.log("Reached replace functions", text, originalString, replaceText);
        if (replaceText)
            text = text.replace(originalString, replaceText);
        else
            text = text.replace(originalString, "");
        return text

    }
 }());
```

Comment: Should it be `localhost:3000/3405?pid=CBM` or `localhost:3000/index.html?pid=CBM` ??

Comment: What error do you get? It should be `req.params` not `req.param`.

Comment: First thing it is not able to render my html page @MohitBhardwaj

Comment: @DavidR I should render my html file and should pass to values one is id and pid...But atleast not even able to render my html page

Comment: GoTo => DevTools => Network tab => Check for html page's path (which will be in 404)

Comment: @DavidR Yes.what is the mistake Iam doing here. can please let me know how to render that html file

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect:

```
res.sendFile(__dirname,'/public/index.html');
```

It should be this:

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
```

Or (a bit more robust):

```
const path = require('path');
...
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
```

As a side note: apparently, if you pass a directory name to `res.sendFile()`, it will send back a 404 response. Not sure that the rationale behind that is.

Comment: .Thanks man..Not sure how I missed that.It worked..How can I can Pass those two values to my client side js file ,so that i can perform other operation?

Comment: Yes I can get those two values.But that is not Iam asking..I've added my client side js file in my question..Where currently Iam hardcoding those values..But I dont want to do that and use the values which I get from /3405?pid=CBM .So how can I send those values from server side get call to client side js file

Comment: Ah, you need to use [templating](http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html) for that (not `res.sendFile()`, which only simply sends a file as a response).

Comment: @robertklep.I dont need those values be used in my html..I need those values in my js file,so that I can perform some db operations

Comment: @user7350714 but to get those values into your client-side JS, you have to pass them _somehow_. A common method is to render them (as JS) into an HTML template (as globals). Or, if possible, the client side code would first perform an XHR request to the backend to retrieve the values.